# What is the purpose of "define.amd = {jQuery: true }" in the code of RequireJS?

Tags: requirejs

Can any one explain with details, why in the `require.js` file the following code is set:

```
define.amd = {
    jQuery: true
};
```

Reference Link: [Default set to jquery as true](http://requirejs.org/docs/download.html#requirejs)

Answer (score 7):

Setting `define.amd` to some value is done to help distinguish the `define` function provided by an AMD loader from any old `define` provided by something else. A typical pattern for code that should handle multiple loading scenarios is this:

```
if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define(['exports'], factory(exports));
} else if (typeof module === 'object' && module.exports) {
    factory(module.exports);
} else {
    factory(exports);
}
```

The first line checks whether you have an AMD loader available, and will use the AMD loader if present. If a `define` function exists but it does not have the `amd` property set, then it is some random foreign `define`.

The name `define` is pretty generic. If it were not for the `amd` property, it would be sometimes difficult to determine whether the `define` that is present is really the one we care about.

---

Setting it to `{ jQuery: true }` is a historical artifact. There's a [pull request to jQuery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/pull/331#issue-779774) that explains it. The author of the request is the author of RequireJS. In brief, the goal there was to indicate that the AMD loader is able to handle the case where multiple versions of jQuery call `define`. jQuery would call `define` only if `define.amd.jQuery` was truthy. It's probably been used by a few versions of jQuery in the past but newer versions no longer use this flag so it is still present mainly for supporting older jQuery versions.